# Do not show a label in windows form chart when that label is 0 - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts

I have a windows form which contains a pie chart (using the chartcontrol).
There are 5 datapoints in this chart which are entered using 5 numericupdown box.
I have a code that plots the pie chart and shows the label as well. However, the chart shows a "0" label when the value is 0 for a datapoint. I do not want that, I want to hide that particular label whose value is 0, and only show those whose value is not 0.
How do I do this? I tried using the chart properties but did not find anything. I also tried the following code, but that didn't work as well:

```
For Each dp As DataPoint In Chart1.Series("Series1").Points
  If dp.YValues(0) <> 0 Then
      dp.IsValueShownAsLabel = True
  End If
Next
```

Checked the chart properties for IsValueShownAsLabel. It is set to "False". The data is coming from numericupdown box in the form using `Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(NumericUpDown1.Value) Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(NumericUpDown2.Value) Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(NumericUpDown3.Value)
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(NumericUpDown4.Value)
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(NumericUpDown5.Value)`

There are 5 datapoints coming from 5 numericupdown boxes.

Also, here is a [image](http://s9.postimg.org/x3ypay47v/Chart.jpg) that shows the chart. The 0.0%  seen the chart is the thing that I do not want. The datapoint for the is set to 0, though it still shows up.

Any helps is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Where did you put this code?  Is it in one of the chart's event handlers?

Comment: So if you remove that For loop, are all of the labels gone?

Comment: @TonyHinkle - No. There still show up. Even after setting the IsValueShownAsLabel to False.

Comment: There is something somewhere setting the IsValueShownAsLabel to True, then.  The default is False, and if you checked the properties of the series and it is false, then they should not be there unless you add them or IsValueShownAsLabel gets set to True somewhere...

Comment: ok I think I found why it is doing this. So I had IsValueShownAsLabel set to True earlier and the Label Text was formatted as "Y Value as Percent of Total". I removed all of those and the code works perfectly. However, now the label shown is "Y Value" and not "Y Value as Percent of Total". How do I get that back to be as percent and not the actual value?

Comment: Instead of showing the label if it's not zero, hide the label if it's zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of showing the labels if they aren't zero, hide them if they are zero:

```
For Each dp As DataPoint In Chart1.Series("Series1").Points
  If dp.YValues(0) = 0 Then
      dp.IsValueShownAsLabel = False
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Ahaa...this works now. But how to change the label from values to "Percent of Total". As I try to do it, the datalabel starts showing up when 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward and works for all:

```
For Each dp As DataPoint In Chart1.Series("Series1").Points
        If dp.YValues(0) = 0 Then
            dp.IsEmpty = True
        Else
            'Show label as "Y Value as Percent of Total" with format as % and precision 1.
            Chart1.Series("Series1").Label = "#VAL{N1}%"
        End If
    Next
```